# Laravel Eloquent belongsToMany and hasMany relationship query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4.2.8.

I have two Eloquent models: `RapidsPacket` and `RapidsQuestion`. A `RapidsPacket` can contain any number of `RapidsQuestion` and a `RapidsQuestion` may be in any number of `RapidsPacket`.

Here are my database tables:

For the RapidsPacket model:

```
packets
 - id
 - name
```

For the RapidsQuestion model:

```
rapids
 - id
 - question
```

And the pivot table:

```
packet_rapid
 - id
 - packet_id
 - rapid_id
```

Here is the current skeleton of the models:

```
class RapidsPacket extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'packets';

    /**
     * Get this packet's questions
     *
     * @return RapidsQuestion
     */     
    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('RapidsQuestion');
    }

}
```

and

```
class RapidsQuestion extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'rapids';

    /**
     * Get this question's packets
     *
     * @return RapidsPacket
     */     
    public function packets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('RapidsPackets');
    }

}
```

What I want to be able to do is grab all questions in a packet, e.g:

```
$packet = RapidsPacket::find(2);
$my_questions = $packet->questions()->get();
```

I also want to be able to get the packets, that a question might belong to. E.g:

```
$question = RapidsQuestion::find(30);
$my_packets = $question->packets()->get();
```

If I try either of the above lines of code and `var_dump()` either `$my_questions` or `$my_packets` I get an enormous object containing all sorts of Laravel things but not the requested data.

I have tried various iterations of passing different foreign and local keys to the `belongsToMany()` function but it never seems to return any models. This is driving me crazy. I've read countless answers on SO and the wider net about this problem but 5 hours down the line and I'm still no further. Please help!

**Update 2:**

Here is the contents of my database tables (v small):

*packets*

```
id: 1
name: test
```

*rapids*

```
id: 30
question: 'sample 1'

id: 40
question: 'sample 2'

id: 50
question: 'sample 3'
```

_packet_rapid_

```
id: 1
packet_id: 1
rapid_id: 30

id: 2
packet_id: 1
rapid_id: 40

id: 3
packet_id: 1
rapid_id: 50
```

**Update 1:**

Just changed RapidsPacket to `belongsToMany` rather than `hasMany` but still to no avail

Comment: `var_dump()` may not be returning what you'd expect.  Try Lê Trần Tiến Trung's solutoin and try `var_dump($my_questions->toArray())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it must be:

```
class RapidsQuestion extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'rapids';

/**
 * Get this question's packets
 *
 * @return RapidsPacket
 */     
public function packets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('RapidsPacket', 'packet_rapid', 'rapid_id', 'packet_id');
}

}
```

.

```
class RapidsPacket extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'packets';

/**
 * Get this packet's questions
 *
 * @return RapidsQuestion
 */     
public function questions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('RapidsQuestion', 'packet_rapid', 'packet_id', 'rapid_id');
}

}
```

I think you should name class and table same, it make you code easier

```
class Rapid extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'rapids';

/**
 * Get this question's packets
 *
 * @return RapidsPacket
 */     
public function packets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Packet', 'packet_rapid');
}

}
```

.

```
class Packet extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'packets';

/**
 * Get this packet's questions
 *
 * @return RapidsQuestion
 */     
public function questions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Rapid', 'packet_rapid');
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd just worked it out before you posted. The major problem was me not calling `get()` afterwards. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: @Garry your biggest problem was not suplying the correct id's of the many-to-many table.

Answer (score 0):

The [oposite of belongsToMany is belongsToMany](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many)

When using hasMany(); it implies that the target has a belongsTo relation to the parent.

To sum up:

```
class RapidsPacket extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'packets';

    /**
     * Get this packet's questions
     *
     * @return RapidsQuestion
     */     
    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('RapidsQuestion');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but I just made that change and it makes no difference. Still doesn't work - I just get an enormous object if I `var_dump()` either `$my_packets` or `$my_questions`